# TLC 5952 Blank pin control

Tags: led, driver

Can BLANK pin of [TLC5952](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc5952) device be permanently connected to ground or does it need to be toggled (once at the startup or each cycle...)?

Answer (score 1):

Blank pin does not need to be used to display changes in LED states, but is required for the fault detection circuits on LEDs. (open (LOD) and short (LSD)

LOD/LSD data are not valid until 1 µs after the falling edge of BLANK.